# 'browser-sync' is not recognized as an internal or external command in VS 2015 as external tool

Tags: visual-studio-2015, browser-sync

I installed browser-sync globally and setup Visual studio using below URL for browser-sync :

https://github.com/peterblazejewicz/visual-studio-web-developer/blob/master/using-browsersync-as-a-tool-in-visual-studio.md

When I run the external tool Browser Sync, I am getting error:

```
'browser-sync' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Can someone tell me what's the issue here, I installed browser sync globally multiple time and also checked in below directory:

```
C:\Users\userName\AppData\Roaming\npm --> i see browser-sync and browser-sync.cmd in that folder.
```

Answer (score 3):

You may need to add a reference to your npm folder in your Path environment variable.  In Windows 7 you do this with the following steps:

1. Start Menu
2. Right-click on Computer and choose Properties
3. On the left window pane (under the Control Panel Home heading) click Advanced system settings (you'll have to be an administrator)
4. Click the Environment Variables button
5. The top list are your individual user account variables and the bottom are system-wide variables; you'll want to edit (or create) a PATH variable in the top section by clicking on the PATH variable and clicking the Edit button or clicking the New button if you don't already have a PATH variable in that section
6. If you are adding a new variable enter PATH as the variable name and the variable value should just be the path to your npm folder (on my system that's C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm)
7. If you are editing an existing variable, go to the end of the current Variable value and add a semi-colon followed by the path to your npm folder (see above)
8. Click OK, OK again, and OK one more time to get back to Control Panel, then you can close that, too
9. You'll have to restart any command windows that were open when you added the item to your PATH variable; they won't automatically detect the updated value